# Can akka handle heavy algorithms to transform data from db?

Tags: akka

I am new to akka and am trying to see if it answers the problematics i am facing. I have data from databases to extract, transform with algorithms and send by and to actors. This involves a lot of computing. 
Can akka handle all this (communication and computing)? Or do i have to call upon another tool to manage the calculus part?

Thank you all.

wip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, all I can offer here is my experience. As a matter of fact I am currently working on something similar (i.e an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) with text files). We're essentially taking a lot of text files and loading their lines up into a PostgreSQL database. This is our setup :

- Intel Xeon 8 cores + SSD
- Files and app on the same machine
- Remote database

We're able to fetch, parse and load *26 millions* file lines and creating specific database indices in about 12 minutes, which is about *1.3GB* worth of files and *3GB* in database. On a much crappier mono-core and HDD setup we can do it in about 40 minutes.

The good thing about Akka is that it will allow you to save up resources and scale more since several actors can share one thread.

Answer (score 2):

Akka can easily handle many millions of message sends per second, oldie but goodie on this topic here [in this letitcrash.com post](http://letitcrash.com/post/20397701710/50-million-messages-per-second-on-a-single-machine). As long as you factor out blocking operations in separate dispatchers (thread pools) the actor model eases parallel computations a lot, which of course gives you nice wall-clock-time in such data crunching apps.

Comment: @LMEyer Ok, thanks. For your information, i am asked to elaborate a network whose nodes can create data extracted from dictionaries (db), transfer it to other nodes, while receiving data and transforming it according to its own behavior (algorithms)-pretty much ETL as LMeyer said. Do you think it would be... smart (?) to reduce a node to a unique actor?

Comment: No, go for more actors – because 1 actor means 1 mailbox, which means sequential processing. You won't get parallelisation if you only have one actor running (you wouldn't get anything out of Akka basically - there are faster "single queue" systems such as the disruptor. Akka's main strength is parallelisation among actors).

Comment: I had the feeling it was no good or at least sub-efficient... Is it more like follows? Dedicate an actor for each operation of my process of what i call a source (i.e. node of the network, actor), or dedicate an actor for each message received by my source or both ?

Comment: It depends which ops can be made parallel, try to think about Actors as asynchronous boundaries - where would they help in your app?